# Is it possible to create a chart in OpenOffice calc using columns and rows?

Tags: openoffice-calc, libreoffice-calc

Is it possible in OpenOffice Calc to create a single chart where one set of data is derived from columns, and another set of data is derived from rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible (i tested it with LibreOffice 3.5 - but i'm sure it works the same way with OpenOffice):

- Starting with these values...

  [image: Values]
- Select cells `A1:B5`, add chart, select "`Line`" type, select "`Points and Lines`" style (should work with other chart types and styles, too):

  [image: Wizard1]
- In the next step, select "`Data series in columns`", both `First Row` / `First Column` as label:

  [image: Wizard2]
- Next step is most important: in the next wizard window, **add the second data series manually**. To do so, hit the <kbd>Add</kbd> button and set Name and Y-Values manually:

  [image: Wizard3a]

  [image: Wizard3b]
- Now, hit <kbd>Finish</kbd>. The result will look similar to this:

  [image: Chart]

The only limitation is that you can't set differenct captions for the different Y axis values - in my example, you will have to decide to use either A2:A5 or B7:E7.